# How do I search for a file by name in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working inside a large legacy project that has a rich file structure. I know the name of the file I need to edit. But I don't remember where it is in the tree! In XCode I would use the filter in the project file view. But there doesn't seem to be something like that in Android Studio. What do I do?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and enter the `filename`.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> are usually used for searching for a specific word inside a scope be it the Directory, Module or the entire Project.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, learned something. Also learned from your answer. But -- if the file is not in your recent files, what you propose here won't work well. I have a project where just typing in the name of the file I was looking for brings up more than a screenfull of results and if the file hadn't been in Recent (which it wasn't the first time I looked) I would not have found it.

Comment: It totally depends on your use case, for eg. layout files have no class names and will not give the right result with `Find in Path`. But will take you to the exact file using Double Shift press. Yes, sometimes it gives a lot of narrowed down results. But I personally find Double Shift press alot faster than `Find in Path`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of how to deal with this - using the Find in Path search (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) search for "class ". Since file names correspond to class names in Java and Kotlin, you will get the file that contains the class definition in your list of results. If there are many classes that start with the same prefix, you can check the "Words" checkbox at the top of the Find in Path dialog.